# Java: JDateChooser shows wrong month

Tags: java, eclipse, jdatechooser, jcalendar

I'm doing super simple form in Eclipse and I'm using JDateChooser from jcalendar 1.4. I add the component in a Jframe, run the code, the date chooser seems to be correct but when I select a date, the component shows the name of the month instead of 30/11/2020

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

[image]

```
package a_vistas;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test frame = new Test();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Test() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser();
        dateChooser.setDateFormatString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        dateChooser.setBounds(71, 43, 259, 20);
        contentPane.add(dateChooser);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example works for me with `JCalendar` 1.4 and Java 1.8. I'm not sure it'll help, but you might look in your class path for an older version.

[image: calendar test]

As tested:

```
import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Test frame = new Test();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public Test() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser(new Date());
        dateChooser.setLocale(new Locale("es"));
        dateChooser.setDateFormatString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        add(dateChooser);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```